# How will an Emlish app respond to high frequency updates?

Tags: f#, elmish

If an Elmish app were to receive updates faster than it can render the view, will it queue each update and resulting model change and try to render them one by one, or will it accumulate the resulting model and only render it whenever it gets a gap?

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if you would implement an elmish app? It depends on the point of bottleneck, but it would certainly be a good idea to wait with visualisation until the model is computed until the latest delta.